# Save file, that defaults to txt extension on save, as csv

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I save a file where the extension says csv but is really a txt file (it's a Cognos issue) as a true csv file?

```
This file:     H:\TEST_DROP\Files\abc.csv  (actually Unicode Text)
Resaved as:    H:\TEST_DROP\Files\abc.csv  (save as CSV comma delimited)
```

Currently doing it this way:

```
olMail.Attachments.Item(j).SaveAsFile strFolder & olMail.Attachments.Item(j).FileName
```

That copies the file as is. It needs to be changed to true CSV comma delimited.

If I manually open the file & save the file it defaults the extension to .txt even though .csv appears in the file name.

Even though we can copy it over with the CSV extension it is causing issues upstream requiring someone to resave it as .csv comma delimited.

My thought was to briefly open it in Notepad and resave it with the csv (comma delimited) extension since it wants to default to the *.txt extension.

Here is the issue that originates the problem (however no resources to address at present) https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-modify-csv-file-format-cognos

Comment: CSV is a kind of text file... What exactly do you mean by _"it's really a txt file"_? Does it use a different delimiter (like tab instead of comma)?

Comment: File extensions are just for us mere puny humans to be able to tell what's what - and the OS uses them to determine what program to launch when we open them -- but really it's all smokes and mirrors: `.csv`, `.txt`, `.dat`, `.html`, `.json`, makes no difference whatsoever and doesn't change anything in the file's contents... which is, at the end of the day, nothing but text. Sounds like you need to tweak your Windows Explorer settings to stop hiding known extensions (IIRC it hides them by default).

Comment: @bassfader Even though it shows extension CSV there is something (due to the Cognos download process) causing it carry a *.TXT ...I dunno....would you call it "semblance" ? The Cognos issue can't be fixed now, so course seems to be open/resave (since simple saveas doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: So, can anyone share code to open & resave a text file with csv comma delimeted?

Comment: @Mathieu....totally agree.  But upstream components hanging on this small issue.  Just need code snip to open & save as csv comma delimited....

Comment: Intervening and saving it with CSV comma delimited would save a step or two and some time and error upstream at clients company where it is being swept....

Comment: The first thing to do is to make Windows Explorer stop hiding known file extensions, so when you look at a filename you get the full story. Not sure what the "upstream" issue is, Excel is more than happy to import CSV data from any text file, regardless of its extension - and I'd even say that doing it this way is *safer*, since Excel has the nasty habit of trying to be smart about CSV files, and wreck data that is perfectly fine in the file itself.

Comment: @bassfader
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-modify-csv-file-format-cognos

Comment: @Mathieu
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-modify-csv-file-format-cognos

Comment: @Mathieu  We don't want to include Excel in the process.

Comment: @Mathieu  Extensions are not hidden

Comment: How about if I restate the issue:
**Can anyone share code to open & resave a text file with csv comma delimeted? **

Comment: Or better: "how to replace the extension in a file name"... which is very likely already answered somewhere...

Comment: @Mathieu If it was only that easy.....Ok, I'm gonna search elsewhere.  Thank you.

Comment: The extension issue seems like a red herring here - according to the link above the issue is the the file *is not comma-delimited*: if that's the case then exactly what is the delimiter?  It's not a simple as just changing the extension.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> olMail.Attachments.Item(j).SaveAsFile strFolder & olMail.Attachments.Item(j).FileName
> ```

The `.FileName` includes the file extension; you want to strip it, and to do this you can use simple string manipulation funtions:

```
Dim originalName As String
originalName = olMail.Attachments.Item(j).FileName

Dim strippedName As String
stripppedName = Left$(originalName, InStrRev(originalName, ".") - 1)
```

Or, you could use a `FileSystemObject` (reference the `Scripting` library); the `GetBaseName` function takes a path/filename and returns the filename stripped of its file extension:

```
Dim originalName As String
originalName = olMail.Attachments.Item(j).FileName

With New FileSystemObject
    Dim strippedName As String
    strippedName = .GetBaseName(originalName)
End With

Dim renamed As String
renamed = strippedName & ".csv"
```

Comment: @Mathieu...Cool, let me give it a try.